# Bring up macos print file dialog

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I found [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/tk_mac.html#:%7E:text=args%20%7Bmy_open_document%20%24f%7D%0A%7D-,%3A%3Atk%3A%3Amac%3A%3APrintDocument%20file,path%20as%20an%20argument.,-%3A%3Atk%3A%3Amac%3A%3AQuit)(::tk::mac::PrintDocument) when going through the Tcl/Tk Man pages and a question I had a few months ago: "How can I print out a document with tkinter on mac or other systems?". If any of y'all know how to do that I would greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this does what you think it does. It's not a function you can call in order to print a document. Rather, if your script defines a tcl procedure with that name (`::tk::mac::PrintDocument`), that procedure will be called via applescript and passed a filename. You will then be responsible for actually printing the file somehow.

For slightly more information see [Platform Menus](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#platformmenus) on tkdocs.com.

Comment: I believe there's code in 8.7 for actually printing now. It's one of those things that's complicated because of wildly different interpretations of what "printing" means, depending on what people need their applications to do.

Comment: @DonalFellows can you send me that or add an answer? By printing I mean it allows you to connect to a printer and shows the menu used in preview and docs